# Is it possible for javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform method to write an incomplete/invalid XML doc without throwing an Exception

Tags: java, xml, exception, transform

I have a method that updates a specific node's text content in a XML document. Is it possible for the below method to write an invalid/incomplete XML document without throwing an exception?

Transformer doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html

```
private static void updateUserNode(String nodeMatchValue, String updateNodeValue, String fileName) throws Exception {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(fileName);

    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

       Node node = list.item(i);

       if (node == null) continue;

       if (nodeMatchValue.equals(node.getTextContent())) {
           node.setTextContent(updateNodeValue);
       }
    }

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(AppProperties.tmpDir + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

Thank you,

Tom

Comment: Anything is possible.  For instance, one could shut the power off mid-write, which would create an incomplete file.  Are you suggesting your code has seen this occur without the power being pulled?  Or is this a hypothetical exercise?

Comment: I suppose if you managed to terminate abruptly without flushing or closing the output stream you might truncate the output.

Comment: What @CodeChimp and Jim are trying to say is, "no" :)

Comment: This did happen, but I don't know if the above code generated the invalid XML. That's what I'm trying to determine. There were no other exceptions and everything seemed normal, ie: power on, no hard drive space issues, network functional, etc... It's possible the invalid XML came from another source.

Comment: The only way to tell for sure would be to recreate it and/or dig through the source of the java code to see if it's possible.  I would think, or at least hope, that any fault or lack of completing a write would result in some sort of exception.  Your code does not have any try/catch, but if the underlying code did throw a Runtime, that should bubble up anyway.  Is it possible you might be suppressing exceptions further up the call stack?

Comment: @CodeChimp I agree, if there was an issue the underlying XML library should complain and throw an Exception. The calling code doesn't catch, it just throws everything... Thank you for your input.